# if there is submenu, replace anchor tag with span tag

Tags: jquery, mmenu

i need to replace anchor tag of items **which has a submenu with class dropdown-menu** with span tag. below is my menu, where i would like to replace `<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/products/">Products</a>` to `<li><span href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/products/">Products</span>`

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/en/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/about-us/">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/products/">Products</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/products/?c=01-hooks">Hooks</a></li>
<li><a href="https://kenovoeesti.ee/products/?c=02-tracks">Tracks</a></l>
...
```

previously i used this script:

```
if($(window).width() <= 939){
     $('#main-menu li:has(.dropdown-menu) > a').replaceWith(function() {
return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
 });
}
```

which did it's job very well. but after upgrade [mmenu plugin](https://mmenujs.com/) (mobile menu plugin i use on that site) to version 8, it doesn't work anymore. i can't figure out, why...? please check [this site](https://kenovoeesti.ee/contact/)  with developer tool.

Comment: Hey, Your code is working. See this http://jsfiddle.net/L7kn6ety/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
$('#main-menu li:has(.dropdown-menu) > a').each(function(e){
$(this).contents().unwrap().wrap("<span></span>")
})
```